# Which heroes can escape Zarya's ult?

Tags: overwatch

Zarya's ult pulls in enemies and bunches them together for a short period of time. As far as I can tell, there is no way to walk out of it or jump out of it with normal movement options.

Are there any heroes that can escape the ult using their abilities? Are there limitations to those escapes?

Heroes that I think might be able to escape (none of these tested or confirmed, listed in no particular order):

- Tracer (blink, rewind)
- Junkrat (bomb jump)
- Winston (jump jets)
- Pharah (jump jets)
- Reaper (Wraith form, REAPositioning?)
- Genji (dash)
- Mercy (guardian angel)
- Widowmaker (grappling hook)
- D.Va (jets, nerf this?)
- Reinhardt (charge)
- McCree (dodge roll?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update: As of  July 2017, Zarya's gravitational surge now disables all movement abilities of affected heroes preventing their escape.

Some abilities, however, do remain unaffected, as they are not true "movement" abilites:

- Orisa's Fortify is designed to let her escape effects like this.
- Reaper's Wraith Form isn't a movement ability as much it is an immunity ability.
- Moira's Fade works like Reaper's Wraith form, granting immunity and escape.

Comment: It's noteworthy (although not for this specific question) that some heroes can effectively nullify the effect of Zarya's ultimate (and, with any luck, resulting ultimates from her team-mates) by going invulnerable, namely Mei and Zenyatta.

Comment: Thus answer is now innaccurate as of 27 July 2017 - would you mind updating it please.

Comment: @ForceGaia updated

Comment: thanks, jsut added an edit myself as it seems you didn't know of a couple of expections that seem like moevment, but are not

Comment: It actually kinda annoys me that Sombra's translocator is disabled during Graviton Surge now.  It's not technically a movement ability because it's an instant teleport.

Comment: Having said that, I can see why she couldn't toss it, but that still doesn't explain why an already set translocator can't be used.

Answer (score 5):

> These heroes have the capability to actually escape a Graviton Surge after getting trapped in one:
>
> Tracer can use a Recall to escape, or two quick Blinks.
>
> Reinhardt can use a Charge to escape.
>
> Genji can use a Swift Strike to get out of it.
>
> Reaper can use Wraith Form to escape.
>
> D.va can use her Boosters to escape.
>
> Widowmaker can use her Grappling Hook to escape."

[Source](http://www.furiouspaul.com/overwatch/zarya.html)

Per this guide (which I personally found very helpful, it's far more than just tactics, it explains counters in-depth as well along with specific information about each ability), those are the only heroes currently (as of June 3rd 2016) capable of escaping, and he specifically listed how he thought it was weird that winston and pharah were unable to escape considering the strength of their jumps.

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm from experience that Pharah, Winston, and Junkrat cannot use their respective jumps to escape. The fact of which makes me sad.

Answer (score 4):

As of the July 27 2017 patch, the answer changed. Now all movement abilities are blocked.

So now there are the following ways to escape:

- Orisa: Fortify
- Zenyatta's Ult (immunity)
- Mercy's Ult if there's someone in range to rez (short immunity)

---

> **Zarya**
>
> ```
> Graviton Surge
>     Now disables mobility abilities on all affected targets
> ```
>
> Developer Comment: In the past, the abilities that allowed heroes to escape Zarya’s Graviton Surge felt fairly arbitrary. We’re cleaning this up and increasing Graviton Surge's overall power by rendering all movement abilities unusable when an enemy is trapped.

Comment: Wrong, it's just Orisa

Comment: What do you mean, it's just Orisa? The patch notes don't mention her and I just confirmed ingame that Mercy cannot fly out by targetting a player outside.

Comment: Reaper can too, as wraith form isn't classed as movement. The general rule is if you can use it in junkrat's trap, you can use it in graviton surge. Of course in that example reaper doesn't escape, only precents him taking more damage while trapped.

Comment: Orisa is the only hero who can escape from Graviton Surge. The answer is not "none", it's just Orisa

Comment: What about reaper w/ wraith and zenyatta w/ her ult? I'll update the answer then.