# Can any attacks knock an enemy out of a Zarya ult?

Tags: overwatch

Certain enemies caught in a Zarya *Graviton Surge* can escape as answered in [Which heroes can escape Zarya's ult?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270734/which-heroes-can-escape-zaryas-ult/270741#270741) but can you or your allies accidentally knock an enemy out of the surge once they have been sucked in?

For example if a Winston in *Primal Rage* starts swinging at enemies caught in the ult will they get knocked out?

Comment: Several times I'd knock opponents out by accident as Rein. >_<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Can you knock enemies out of an allied Zarya's ult?

#### Yes.

Abilities and attacks that can take enemies out of an allied Zarya's ult include things like Roadhog's hook, Reinhardt Charge. However, not all attacks can knock enemies out.  Pharah's Concussive Blast, although strong enough on its own to knock players far away, does little to nothing in a Graviton Surge as it will pull the player right back before they can escape the ult.  Same goes for Winston's ultimate -- despite how strong it is, playing as Winston I have never been able to knock enemies out of an ult -- as it will only deal damage.

Comment: Assuming this applies to Roadhogs ultimate too, since it's multiple small knockbacks which get negated by the counter-pull of Graviton? I'm always scared to drop a Graviton if there's a Roadhog nearby who might push everything out of it :<

Comment: No. Roadhog's ult combos with Zarya's ult. No one is getting knocked out.

Comment: I didn't account for hooks or pins in my answers since it fell like an obvious thing because it's the litteral definition of the ability. But yeah, those are pretty much the 2 only things that does get people out of that (allied wise)

Answer (score -1):

Getting knocked out of it ? I don't think so. Never seen it happen either. Getting pinned or hooked out of it will happen though.

They'd be sucked right back in if they were knocked out by any sort of blast from their enemies(that is something that I saw and experienced).

Maybe combining the knock back from enemies with an escape that doesn't quite get you out of it. Like a Pharah or a Junkrat that tries to escape with a concussive or a rocket jump.

Comment: OP is asking about this the other way around. (like if a Reighhart charges in, he can pull someone out of the well) - Also, [we have people that tested ways of escaping the well if you're caught inside.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/270739/51332)

Comment: @NBN-Alex This looks like they've understood the question. If someone was also trying to escape at the same time, then maybe someone else's ability would be able to knock them out.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. I'll try to precise a bit.